# RegEx to match all text between two strings that slightly alter

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, air

I am currently working on an AIR app and I'm trying to get a certain block of text from a website where that block of text is always between two specific strings that contain links that change from page to page.

It looks something like this:

```
<p><a href="**changes**">Previous Chapter</a> <a href="**changes**"><span style="float: right">Next Chapter</span></a></p>
.
.
_desired content_
.
.
<p><a href="**changes**">Previous Chapter</a> <a href="**changes**"><span style="float: right">Next Chapter</span></a></p>
```

*The two strings are identical

Now, I have tried several RegEx expressions but without success. I just can't get my head around Regex in general...

The last expression I've tried is: `/(?<=<p><a href=\".+\">Previous Chapter<\/a> <span style=\"float: right\"><a href=\".+\">Next Chapter<\/a><\/span><\/p>)(.*)(?=<p><a href=\".+\">Previous Chapter<\/a> <span style=\"float: right\"><a href=\".+\">Next Chapter<\/a><\/span><\/p>)/gsi`
but that one isn't even being recognized as a RegEx.

I would really appreciate any help with the subject.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks to ***Organis***'s help I managed to solve the problem, it was indeed easier and better NOT using RegEx.
This is what i ended up doing:

```
text=text.split("Next Chapter<\/span><\/a><\/p>")[1].split("Previous Chapter<\/a>")[0];
text=text.substring(0,text.lastIndexOf("<p><a href"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use **RegEx**. Read why: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/.

Extract text between two fixed `<span style="float: right">Next Chapter</span></a></p>`, then cut finalizing `<p><a href="**changes**">Previous Chapter</a> <a href="**changes**">` off.

Comment: Thank you! it worked perfectly :)